# Physical Terminal (DEC VT220) issues with ZSH

Tags: terminal, zsh, hardware

I recently purchased a VT220 and all the hardware necessary to hook it to my macbook pro.  After several hours of fiddling I got it working with a shell - my only problem is my shell of choice, ZSH, behaves weirdly. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and Arrow keys, as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> do not actually move the cursor and while they do delete it is kind of awkward.

Using BASH on the other hand, the device works flawlessly.  Is there an issue with some control character or something that ZSH is using?

Comment: Did you try `export TERM=vt220`?

Comment: I had not - that FIXED IT!!! Thank you very much.  Is there a way I can have it do this automatically on this specific console but not my other consoles? I'd throw it in my zshrc but that would do every console...

Comment: The default value of TERM is normally specified by the getty process accepting the serial connection.  If this were Linux, you might run getty like `/sbin/getty 115200 ttyS0 vt220`.  This will set TERM to vt220 when accepting any login over ttyS0.  I'm not sure of the MacOS equivalent.

Comment: Third column in `/etc/ttys` on OS X.